# Issue with sending % in password by converting password in data using NSUTF8StringEncoding server not accepting

Tags: ios

When i have % character in password then after NSUTF8StringEncoding to data its not getting accepted by server.Do not know whats the issue with %.With all other special character its working fine excluding this.From server side getting 400 status code i.e Bad Request.

Comment: is your web service a POST request? If not make it to POST, issue will be solved

Comment: its post only we are sending as data in httpbody but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to url encode the password. This should solve the problem.